# Run multiple rsync commands via ssh and only enter ssh passphrase once

Tags: bash, macos, ssh, rsync, synology

I am syncing multiple folders between an iMac and Synology NAS via multiple rsync calls contained in a script.  How to I add ssh with a private/public key and passphrase such that I only have to enter the passphrase once when the script is run but have all the rsync commands utilize the secure ssh tunnel?

```
rsync -rtv --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fgo=r --delete --exclude='.*' /Users/Username/FolderName/ username@ipaddress::Foldername/
```

This is the template for each rsync call with with no ssh.  The folder name is different in each rsync call.

I can generate the ssh private/public keys with a passphrase and upload the public key to the NAS and incorporate it into authorized_keys file.  I understand the syntax to add ssh to the rsync commands.  I have no idea how via a script only enter the passphrase once for the 7 rsync commands that run in the script.
Any input that would point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SSH keys for scripting, you don't want to use a passphrase. OpenSSH doesn't provide a way to enter passphrases except on a TTY, and the only way to use a TTY to enter a passphrase is to use something like [Expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) to handle the passphrase entry, which is needlessly complex.

Instead, you should use filesystem permissions and, if necessary, a dedicated user to control access to the keys.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It sounds like the way to go.

Comment: Can I use the ssh-agent add feature which will give me the opportunity to add the passphrase to the apple keychain.  Then at best I would have to select the passphrase every time I run an rsync command over ssh?

Comment: Yes, you can save the passphrase in the Keychain, in which case it can be used again and again. There's [an article on how to do that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically). The only restriction is that you have to be logged in as that user so the Keychain is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Unix and Linux have commands called "ssh-add" and "ssh-agent".  ssh-add saves
private key passwords in memory, and ssh-agent can retrieve them for use by ssh
or sftp.

You can use ssh-add to enter the password one time (e.g. when you boot your
machine) and the password will then be available for ssh or sftp until the next
re-boot.

For more information, here is a link:

```
https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/agent
```